# Prove that I(n) is a strictly decreasing series: I(n)= $\int_0^1 \frac{(x^n)}{(x+1)} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Prove that $I(n)$ is a strictly decreasing series:
$$I(n)=  \int_0^1 \frac{(x^n)}{(x+1)} dx.$$
If it were just decreasing I would have used the fact that when $x$ is between $0$ and $1$ ($0$ and $1$ are included), $x^n \geq x^{n+1}$. Then divide by $x+1$ and integrate. But I found the version of the same problem where it states that it has to be strictly decreasing. Any ideas?

Comment: The value of the integrand at discrete points like the one at 0 or 1 doesn't matter for the integral. Can you elaborate more what you mean by the comment?

Comment: I was using the fact that if f(x)<g(x) than $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ < $\int_a^b g(x)dx$, of course when x is from [a,b]. The statement f(x)<g(x) has to be true for all values in [a,b] for this trick to work. It has been solved below with the mean value theorem for integrals, which apparently works with two functions integrated.

Comment: No it doesn't. If $f(x)<g(x)y$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ except for a finite number of points where $f(x)$ is $77$ and $g(x)$ is $0$, then the integral over $g$ is still larger than that over $f$. Isolated points are ignored by the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Mean Value Theorem for Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_integration) states

> If $f$ is continuous and $g$ is positive and integrable, then there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that
>   $$ \int_a^b f(x)g(x) \, dx = f(c) \int_a^b g(x) \, dx. $$

Applying this with $f(x)=x$, $g(x) = \frac{x^n}{x+1}$ gives
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n+1}}{x+1} \, dx = c\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{x+1} \, dx, $$
where $0<c<1$, which is what we wanted.

Comment: Didn't know this exists. I thought this worked with only one function: $\int_a^b f(x)$ = (b-a)f(c)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.**

A continuous non-negative function $f$ having a strictly positive value has a stricly positive integral.

You can apply this to the function $g(x)=\frac{x^n}{x+1}-\frac{x^{n+1}}{x+1}$.

Comment: yes, but g(0)=g(1)=0...

Comment: What about $g(1/2)$?

Comment: To be sure that the integral is strictly positive (>0) the function you integrate must also be strictly positive for all values between a and b, where a and b are the start and end of the integration interval [a,b]. In our case a=0 and b=1. Because your function mentioned g takes value 0 in a=0 and b=1 you aren't sure that it's integral is strictly positive. Yes it is greater or equal($\geq$), but you aren't sure that it is >0... The integral could also take value 0 in some points, theoretically speaking... We all know it is strictly above 0, but I can't prove it...

Comment: This is wrong. If the function is continuous, it needs to be strictly positive at least one point. This implies it is strictly positive on an interval. It doesn't need to be strictly positive on the full interval of integration.